# What is the unit of the LineFormat.Weight property in Microsoft Office Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, excel

I have searched the Microsoft documentation and have found no information.

Comment: The example for [`Shape.Line`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.shape.line) implies that `LineFormat.Weight` is in points.

Answer (score 0):

The answer, after setting a line to a weight of 100 and printing it out, would seem to be 0.01 inches. And apparently Microsoft does call that a point, even though the usual definition of a point is 1 / 72 of an inch.